# A case study of colon punctuation usage

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

I wonder if the three colon punctuation usage in the case bellow. Also, is the indent proper? Finally, are they formal usage, which can be used in formal writings?

```
I have two questions:
     1: Who am I?
     2: Where did I come from?
```

Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Although I agree with @brasshat's answer overall, I would go further and say the way you have punctuated your example is very strange. Where did you see that? Do you have a source to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you take to introducing and punctuating a numbered list is purely a style decision. The style that I see used most often is the one endorsed by the *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003), which discusses both numbered lists (of the type you use) and unnumbered lists (of the same type) under the category name "vertical lists":

> **6.127** *Vertical lists: punctuation and format.* A vertical list is best introduced by a complete grammatical sentence followed by a colon [unless the vertical list is presented in paragraph style]. Items carry no closing punctuation unless they consist of complete sentences. If the item are numbered, a period follows the numeral and each item begins with a capital letter. ...
>
> [Example:] To purge files protected by Delete Sentry, start with the following steps:
>
> 1. From the Microsoft Tools group, choose the Undelete icon.
> 2. To select the directory from which you want to purge files, choose the Drive/Dir button.
> 3. In the Undelete screen, select the files you want to purge.

*Words Into Type*, third edition (1974), has similar, though not identical, advice for numbered lists:

> In lists numerals with periods are preferable to numerals with parentheses.
>
> [Example:]
>
> 1. Call for help.
> 2. Stop the bleeding.
> 3. Keep the patient warm.
>
> ...
>
> **Lists.** A colon is used after an introductory statement that contains the words as follows or the following; either a colon or a period may be used after other statements introducing lists.
>
> [Example:] We will discuss the following types of psychotherapy:
>
> 1. Client-centered therapy
> 2. Rational-emotive therapy
> 3. Behavioral therapy
> 4. Psychoanalysis
>
> When the introduction is not a complete sentence and one or more of the items of the list are needed to complete it, no colon or dash should be used.
>
> [Example:] Two types of psychotherapy are
>
> 1. Client-centered therapy
> 2. Rational-emotive therapy

Oxford University Press's *Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) offers quite similar dvice, too:

> It is OUP style to use full points [periods] after numbers in lists, though not after items in a displayed list unless one or more of them is a complete sentence:
>
> [Example:] He was prosecuted in the court of Aragon on three charges:
>
> 1. for having caused the death of Escovedo, falsely pretending the King's authority
> 2. for having betrayed secrets of State and tampered with ciphered dispatches
> 3. for having fled from justice when his conduct was judicially investigated
>
> The list above could equally have been styled as a single displayed sentence, with a semicolon at the end of the first element, a semicolon and  and at the end of the second element, and a full point at the end of the last. If every element in a displayed list forms a complete sentence, however, a full point follows each sentence:
>
> [Example:] He was prosecuted in the court of Aragon on three charges:
>
> 1. He caused the death of Escovedo, falsely pretending the King's authority.
> 2. He betrayed secrets of State and tampered with ciphered dispatches.
> 3. He fled from justice when his conduct was judicially investigated.

It thus appears that *Chicago*, *Words into Type*, and *Oxford* would concur in treating your example this way:

> I have two questions:
>
> 1. Who am I?
> 2. Where did I come from?

This doesn't mean that using an alternative approach to styling your list (such as following the numerals in your numbered list with colons instead of periods) is wrong, but it does suggest a tendency in published usage to prefer periods after numerals.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing **wrong** with the "three colon" usage in most cases, although it might not conform to the style guide of some particular organization. It's largely a matter of personal preference, though I must confess it's not **my** personal preference, particularly in the use of the colon after the numbers in the numbered list. There my preference would be to use a different character, either a period ("."), or a closing parenthesis (")") where you have the colon. Sometimes when I am particularly detail oriented, I'll use both the closing parenthesis and the period. As to the first colon, in the particular example you cite, I'd not be likely use the first colon, either. My general rule of thumb is to use a colon if the part of the sentence before it is a sentence fragment, and to use a comma or semi-colon to differentiate the choices, with normal punctuation after the last option with or without an "and" before the penultimate choice, so

> Two questions:
>
> ```
> 1. Who am I; [and]
>
> 2. Where did I come from?
> ```

But if the part of the sentence before where the colon would be is a complete sentence, as it is in the example you cite, I just use normal punctuation, so

> I have two questions.
>
> ```
> 1: Who am I?
>
> 2: Where did I come from?
> ```

Whether to indent or not is a matter of personal preference and the style guide you're are using. With just two options, I might just run them on, but with more, I'll list them, with or without an indentation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the colon being used in two entirely different ways, and, together, they will seem a bit odd to some people (though I don't find the combo that upsetting).

Colon can be used a the end of an introductory sentence or phrase to mark the end of that and the start of the thing being introduced.  (Eg, "I have a question:  What the heck were you thinking when you did that?")  Note that the colon, in this case, indicates a pause in the spoken words somewhat greater than a comma or semicolon, but less than a period.

(Your case is a little odd because the following "thing being introduced" is a visual list rather than something intended to be spoken, but arguably, if it were spoken, the pause would be about the same as in my example above.)

Colon can also be used in lists, as a separator between a list enumerator and the corresponding list item.  It is one of several styles of doing this (others being, eg, ".", "--", ")", etc).  In such a case the colon is not really "punctuation", in the sense of something that modifies the pace of the spoken words, but is purely a visual clue.